# Finding duplicated or repeated character in a string and return the number of repeation in Java

Tags: java, count, return, duplicates, character

I have created a Java program to find duplicated character in a String and tell how many times this character is duplicated.

I have created two arrays with the same characters, and two for loops that compare the first element of the first array with all characters in the second array,and so as for the second element,
Here is my code:

```
Scanner console=new Scanner(System.in);
char[] array=console.next().toCharArray();
char[] array2=array;
int count=0;
char m;
for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<array2.length; j++) {
        if (array[i]==array2[j]) {
            count=count+1;
        } // end if
    } //end loop inner
    if ( count>=2) {
        System.out.println(array[i]+" is duplicated "+count+" times!");
    } // end 2nd if
    count=0;
} //end outer loop
```

an example of my output is:
aabb

```
a is duplicated 2 times!
a is duplicated 2 times!
b is duplicated 2 times!
b is duplicated 2 times!
```

As you can see my problem is that if a character is repeated two times it prints two lines saying its duplicated two times, and i know the reason behind this but i dont know how to solve it!. I dont want to use hashmap, because until now i have only studied if/else, loops, and lately something about arrays, so if your answer lies among this subjects thanks!

Comment: You don't need HashMap, you could do it with an integer array where index of the array is the ascii value of character. Assuming charset is ASCII

Comment: believe me i really dont get what you say, consider me as a nooby, only if you give me the code, then maybe i understand

Comment: I have answered with the code and logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use an Object (here a `String`) to keep track of the already encountered characters.

```
Scanner console=new Scanner(System.in);
char[] array=console.next().toCharArray();
char[] array2=array;
int count=0;
char m;
String memoryString = "";
for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<array2.length; j++) {
        if (memoryString.contains(String.valueOf(array[i])) break;
        if (array[i]==array2[j]){
            count=count+1;  
        }
    } //end loop inner
    memoryString+=array[i]
    if (count>=2) {
          System.out.println(array[i]+" is duplicated "+count+" times!");
    }
    count=0;
} //end outer loop
```

Comment: thank you very much , your answer was exactly what i want, but if i dont sound stupid can you just tell me what does that memoryString mean? does it store each character automatically after each loop?

Comment: @MahamadHusen That's exactly his role. It stocks your characters and prevent from looping again on a character already encountered. Feel free to upvote/accept the answer :)

Comment: but why when i click upvote it becomes one then becomes 0 again?

Answer (score 0):

you could instead loop through all the possible characters and see how many of them exist in the string (assuming you are ok with using a string instead of an array of characters):

```
while(!str.isEmpty())
{
    int count = 0;
    char c = str.charAt(0);
    while(str.indexOf(c) != -1)
    {
        str = str.replaceFirst(String.valueOf(c), "");
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println("number of " + c + "  " + count);
}
```

Edit: do to the backlash against my (poor) assumption and using a 256 limit on the number of chars, i reworked it a bit. hope this is a bit better!

Comment: This is so horrible. Worse than brute-force.

Comment: yea.. that was not the best assumption. i changed the answer to get rid of that...

Comment: believe me i dont understand this, as i said, the only thing i studied until now is if/else,loops, and something about arrays,i could have used hashmap but i have not studied it at college

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you could do this (Assuming ASCII charset):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console=new Scanner(System.in);
        char[] array=console.next().toCharArray();
        int[] counts = new int[255];

        for(char c : array) {
            counts[c]++;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 255; i++){
            if (counts[i] > 1)
                System.out.println("duplicated char: " + (char)i + ", " + counts[i] + "times");
        }
    }
```

The logic is:

- Create an array of integers to keep track of counts of each input character
- Loop through each character in the string and increment the count. The index of `counts` array will be the ascii value of the character.
- Do a one pass through the counts array to figure out which characters have counts more than 2 and print them.

Comment: Yet again, there are more than 256 characters.

Comment: @Tunaki assuming ASCII charset